# LWC how to refresh the record detail page back to its page after saving it?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have worked on LWC requirement where

1. On Case record, I have customized a component, which is based on custom metadata for the UI display and multi picklist for the back end.
2. As a case owner ONLY I CAN EDIT or selected a picklist, it will display the options based on picklist from the custom metadata(the same value will be in the multi picklist in the backend).
   3)The issues I am having are how can I after saving the record
   a) refresh the page to display the checked boxes and b) disable the picklist chosen but not the options.

```js
import { LightningElement, track,api } from 'lwc';
import checkOwnerId from '@salesforce/apex/checkCaseFieldsCaseOwner.checkCurrentUserIsRecordOwner';
import getCustumMetadata from '@salesforce/apex/checkCaseFieldsCaseOwner.getCustumMetadata';
import updateCasewithChosenvalues from'@salesforce/apex/checkCaseFieldsCaseOwner.updateCasewithChosenvalues';
export default class TodoMultipicklistCustom extends LightningElement {
    @track options=[];
    @api recordId;
    @track checkboxesString;
    
    connectedCallback(){
        checkOwnerId({recordId: this.recordId})
            .then(result => {
                if(result){
                    this.disabled = false;
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
            });
    }

    get brokerOptions() {
        return [
            { label: 'None', value: 'None'},
            { label: 'State Farm Principal Officer', value: 'State Farm Principal Officer' },
            { label: 'State Farm Licensed Team Member', value: 'State Farm Licensed Team Member' }
        ];
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.value = event.detail.value;
        this.options.length=0;
            getCustumMetadata({Type :  this.value })
                .then(result => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                    let  optionsObject;
                    //result.forEach(element => console.log(element));
                    result.forEach(element=>{
                        optionsObject = new Object();
                        optionsObject.label = element;
                        optionsObject.value = element;
                        console.log('+++++options*'+ JSON.stringify(optionsObject))
                        this.options.push(optionsObject);
                        console.log('***'+ JSON.stringify(this.options))
                    });
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.options));
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.error = error;
                });
    }
    handleCheckboxgroup(event) {
        let data;
        data = event.target.value;
        this.checkboxesString=data.split(',').join(':');
        console.log('*****'+ this.checkboxesString);
    }
    updateCase(){
        updateCasewithChosenvalues({
            recordId: this.recordId,
            ToDo_Typ: this.value,
            optionsChecked: this.checkboxesString
        })
        .then(()=>{
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            this.errorMessage=error;
            console.log('unable to save the record due to'+JSON.stringify(this.errorMessage));
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Lightning Data Service's [updateRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_update_record) method to update your Case record instead of using an imperative apex method. The record data refreshes automatically as LDS refreshes the view if the cache is stale.

PS: You could also get the current record details using LDS' getRecord method instead of an Apex call in the case of checking OwnerId.

Answer (score 0):

So i used
.then(result => {
this.Case = result;

```
    window.location.assign('/'+ this.recordId);
})
```

to refresh the page, but I am not able to display the previously saved the multiselect values? Any suggestions why

Answer (score 0):

One can use [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_get_record_notify) `getRecordNotifyChange(recordId)` to refresh the standard salesforce component to refresh (without actually refresh the browser) after saving a field from a custom component provided the custom component in the record page.